# How do I refactor methods with different signatures but almost identical bodies?

Tags: c#, refactoring

Given this private method:

```
private static IEnumerable<LedgerSummary> FilterLedgers(IList<LedgerSummary> ledgers, List<ExcludedLedgerAccount> excludedLedgerAccounts)
{
    var excludedLedgerEntries = ledgers.Where(x => excludedLedgerAccounts.Any(y => y.LedgerAccount == x.LedgerAccount)).ToList();

    var filteredLedgers = ledgers.Except(excludedLedgerEntries).ToList();

    // do some more filtering

    return filteredLedgers;
}
```

and this one:

```
private static IEnumerable<LedgerPosting> FilterLedgers(IList<LedgerPosting> ledgers, List<ExcludedLedgerAccount> excludedLedgerAccounts)
{
    var excludedLedgerEntries = ledgers.Where(x => excludedLedgerAccounts.Any(y => y.LedgerAccount == x.DistributionAccountLedgerAccount)).ToList();

    var filteredLedgers = ledgers.Except(excludedLedgerEntries).ToList();

    // do some more filtering

    return filteredLedgers;
}
```

what's the best way to refactor them so that I'm not repeating what is essentially the same logic in the method bodies?

The reason why it's not so straightforward (*in my mind*) is because the method signatures are slightly different in that one's taking (and returning) a '`List`' of `LedgerSummary`s and the other `LedgerPostings`s, and each of these have different property names (that map to the same properties in `ExcludedLedgerAccount`).

*Unfortunately, I can't change the properties in either of those two classes or to use a common interface, for example, for reasons that would lengthen this discourse!*

I know the answer's really straightforward (so I apologise in advance) but I seem to be having a [programmer's block](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/34867/is-there-such-a-thing-as-programmers-block) at the minute.

Comment: Sounds like the best you can do is extract a method from the first two lines.

Comment: @Yorye: It's not just the first two lines that are similar; there's more which I've replaced with the comment (see code) for brevity. Also, I was more after how I would be able to extract into a common method than the fact that I needed to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this (don't have a VS at hand now, might require a bit of debugging)

```
private static IEnumerable<T> FilterLedgers<T> FilterLedgers(
    IList<T> ledgers, 
    List<ExcludedLedgerAccount> excludedLedgerAccounts,
    Func<T, ExcludedLedgerAccount, bool> selector)
{
    var excludedLedgerEntries = ledgers.Where(x => excludedLedgerAccounts.Any(y => selector(x, y)).ToList();

    var filteredLedgers = ledgers.Except(excludedLedgerEntries).ToList();

    // do some more filtering

    return filteredLedgers;
}
```

And use it:

```
IEnumerable<LedgerSummary> result = FilterLedgers<LedgerSummary>(input, exclude, (i, e) => i.LedgerAccount == e.LedgerAccount);

IEnumerable<LedgerPosting> result = FilterLedgers<LedgerSummary>(input, exclude, (i, e) => i.LedgerAccount == e.DistributionAccountLedgerAccount);
```

Comment: Thanks, @John, I knew I could use some lambda in there. I think I'll go with this; there's some more logic which I left out to avoid it becoming too much code but, again, I could always use another Func.

Answer (score 1):

You can extract a predicate that you're using in the Any extension method:

```
private static IEnumerable<LedgerSummary> FilterLedgersImpl(IEnumerable<LedgerSummary> ledgers, Func<LedgerSummary, LedgerAccount, bool> predicate)
{
    var excludedLedgerEntries = 
        ledgers
           .Where(x => excludedLedgerAccounts.Any(y => predicate(x, y)))
           .ToList();

    var filteredLedgers = ledgers.Except(excludedLedgerEntries).ToList();

    // do some more filtering

    return filteredLedgers;
}
```

And then you can use this helper method directly:

```
var list1 = FilderLedgersImpl(ledgers, (x, y) => y.LedgerAccount == x.LedgerAccount);

var list2 = FilderLedgersImpl(ledgers, (x, y) => y.LedgerAccount == x.DistributionAccountLedgerAccount);
```

Comment: Thanks, @Sergey, your answer's very similar to John's so deserves at least an upvote.

Comment: @iDevelApp: Yeah. When I wrote this answer there're no any existing answer at that moment:)

Answer (score 0):

Unless LedgerSummary and LedgerPosting share a common base class that does all the work you need (in which case you could use generics), you can't do much with this.

In C++, you could use templates (or even typedefs) for a nice solution but not in C# or java... unless you wanted to use a code generator.